# ocaml remove duplicates in a list

Tags: list, ocaml

Hey guys I am having a bit of trouble i have a general idea what the code should be but not to sure what to do from here.

The question is: Define a function remove_elts taking a list of items as well as a list of items to
remove from the first list, and returning a list with all occurrences of the items
to be removed gone.

My code is :

```
let remove_elts l reml = 
  match l with
    [] -> false
  | hd :: tl -> 
      if hd = l then reml
      else hd :: remove_elts l tl;;
```

Answer (score 1):

Any filtering function, i.e., a function that takes a container and returns another container that contains elements of the input container that satisfy some property, is implemented using the following algorithm:

```
output-sequence = []
foreach element in the input-sequeunce:
   if element satisfies condition:
      output-sequence := output-sequence + element
```

This iteration has two elements which differ with each step, the `element` variable that takes in order the elements of the `input-sequence` and the output-sequence that grows every time, the `<element>` satisfies the condition.

In functional programming, iteration is commonly represented with recursion which is more natural from the mathematical point of view. Anything that changes in the iteration will become a parameter of the recursive function, and each step is represented as a recursive call with the new values of the variables. So the same iteration in the functional style (pseudocode)

```
filter input-sequence output-sequence =
  if is-empty input-sequence then output-sequence
  else 
      let element = first-element-of input-sequence in
      let rest = drop-first-element input-sequence in
      if element satisfies condition 
      then filter rest (output-sequence + element)
      else filter rest output-sequence
```

And the iteration is called as

```
filter input-sequence []
```

So it is a little bit more verbose then the `foreach` but this is because `foreach` is basically a syntactic sugar.

Now, your task is to implement this in OCaml, keeping in mind two things:

1) In OCaml you can use pattern matching, instead of `is-empty`,`first-element-of`, and `drop-first-element` primitives.

2) You're using a singly-linked list as the sequence, so appending an element to the end of it is very expensive, it is O(N) (as you have to go through all elements, until you reach the end), and doing this in cycle will make your algorithm O(N^2), so instead you should prepend to the beginning (which is O(1)) and at the end of recursion, reverse the list.